Why does my domain redirect to https://255.255.255.255?
I'm new in this area (ubuntu, server, cloud, networking), so I might be doing some obvious mistakes.
I have installed NextCloud using Snap Package and it seems to run well on http, accessible at a forwarded external port; but for https, when executing the sudo nextcloud.enable-https lets-encrypt command, I get the following error:
Domain: ycon.go.ro
Type:   connection
Detail: 79.112.92.172: Fetching
https://255.255.255.255:443/.well-known/acme-challenge/BTIe8laV2OiyRufh_842IhcenZ9ONo9cA0gD5MUbF0k:
   Invalid host in redirect target "255.255.255.255". Only domain
   names are supported, not IP addresses

Mentions:

the ISP gave me a subdomain for dynamic DNS, which is ycon.go.ro, and for that I've requested the certificate;
I know https can be issued for such a domain (.go.ro) as I've seen it at a friend who installed NextCloud with the Debian script;

Also, I have noticed that if I try to open the http://ycon.go.ro domain in the browser, I get redirected to https://255.255.255.255 . Only when opening the domain at the forwarded external port I can see NextCloud running.
What am I doing wrong?

I don't know, but 255.255.255.255 definitely isn't anywhere near a valid IP address. Something is probably very wrong with your server config.

please show us the domain, we can't use the glassball for investigation.

@djdomi right; done

Your server replies 406 Not Acceptable.

@vidarlo On https, yes, but as I don't have a SSL certificate, isn't that normal? And on http, it redirects to 255.255.255.255, as certbot says in the log.

It's not normal - and on http you send a 302 Location. Check you setup, it's somehow fundamentally broken. Furthermore, if you don't have a cert, you can't do HTTPS... something is doing https at that address. There's something about your setup you don't understand. Generally home user / end user questions are off topic, because residential ISPs does stupid things like blocking https or doing CG-NAT.

moreover which webserver is involved? because there is a hard redirection - may wrong tutorial?

As of my understanding, Snap has installed an Apache2 webserver. I'm running on the default installation and configuration files which have resulted after running sudo snap install nextcloud from https://snapcraft.io/nextcloud
And for OS I've installed a clean Ubuntu 20.04.6 before installing NextCloud.

C:\>wget http://ycon.go.ro
--2024-04-15 10:02:22--  http://ycon.go.ro/
Resolving ycon.go.ro... 79.112.92.172
Connecting to ycon.go.ro|79.112.92.172|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://255.255.255.255:443/ [following]

The web server at 79.112.92.172 redirects http to https://255.255.255.255:443/ - you'll need to configure your web server correctly. It's not related to the SSL certificate.

I know I am a noob, but do you have any advice of where (directory or file) should I look in order to find that redirect? NextCloud has been installed with Snap on a clean Ubuntu 20.04, so all configurations should be default at the moment.

The forwarding is configured in your web server.

Such a redirect is by no means "a default".
